App on Ubuntu doesn't show fonts
Here is what I'm seeing:

The app in question is Dolphin Emulator, installed from the Ubuntu app center:

Terminal output has the following warning:

Gtk-WARNING **: 19:49:26.024: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3286:25:
'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

It seems like this might be related.
How can I go about diagnosing and fixing this?

Do you have NVidia graphics?

@ArchismanPanigrahi this machine has intel integrated graphics

You can try earlier version see if they work.

Install it as a native package instead.
First, remove Dolphin Emulator from the app store.
Then, add the PPA.
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dolphin-emu/ppa

Then, run the commands
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dolphin-emu

Now open Dolphin Emulator from the menu.
